# Haskell book Let syntax confusion (parameter reassignment)

Tags: haskell

While going through the Haskell book I came across the following example where it appears in the 4th line of the example here that the result of `f a` is being stored in the `b` argument to `CountMe`, and `n'` I assume is a copy of the value of `n` in the initial bind definition. I haven't seen this type of let clause before, am I correct in my hypothesis above or is something else happening. Also, is this a common use of a let clause, it seems rather confusing?

```
instance Monad CountMe where
    return = pure
    CountMe n a >>= f = 
      let CountMe n' b  = f a
      in CountMe (n + n') b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably easier to understand if written this way:

```
instance Monad CountMe where
  return = pure
  CountMe n a >>= f = case f a of
      CountMe n' b -> CountMe (n + n') b
```

This pattern matching of `f a` to the pattern `CountMe n' b`, giving values to the variables `n'` and `b`, can also be done in a `let` or `where` clause, with the same result. The main difference to a `case` is that the latter can also have, well, multiple different cases, but in this case there's only one constructor so only one case needs to be matched.

Comment: There is a subtle difference: `let` performs lazy (irrefutable) pattern matching, while `case` does strict pattern matching. For a writer-like monad like this, probably it does not matter much (and the strict variant seems more appropriate, anyway).

Answer (score 3):

If you refers the definition of `>>=` in [Control.Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--62--61-). You will find that the type of `f` is:

```
(a -> CountMe b)
```

So, the hypothesis:

> The result of `f a` is being stored in the b argument to CountMe.

is **Wrong**. the result of `f a` is `CountMe n' b`.

and the next hypothesis:

> n' I assume is a copy of the value of n in the initial bind definition.

is also **Wrong**. The value of `n'` is not a copy of `n`, what is the value of `n'` depending on the what the function `f` do.

As you may have known, the common using of let clause is to store Intermediate result which attempt to apply repeatly in `in` clause. Here is a example:

```
let m = mean xs in (m^2, m*2)
```

The confusing thing here is due to can't get the value of `n'` and `b` from `CountMe` data type directly. it need to use **pattern matching** feature to extract such values. If you have defined functions to get such values, say,

```
getCountMe_N (CountMe n b) = n
getCountMe_B (CountMe n b) = b
```

The let clause can be rewritten as:

```
let cntMe = f a in CountMe (n + getCountMe_N cntMe) (getCountMe_B cntMe)
```

The pattern matching is not restricted using in `let` clause only, actually, it is common used in argument of function, `where` clause and `case` expression, for more information, see: [Pattern matching](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching)